# How to invoke Selenium from Xstudio for implementing Continuous Integration

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration

I am trying to implement continuous integration and have chosen the following tools for the same:
1. Jenkins - to build and deploy the code.
2. Xstudio - for test management and to invoke selenium for testing after deployment.
3. Selenium - for automation testing.
4. JIRA - for bug tracking.

Currently, I have installed XStudio and need help to invoke Selenium installed in other server. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I could successfully invoke selenium from XStudio, the following link will guide through the configuration            http://www.xqual.com/documentation/launchers/selenium_java.html.    Please include additional classpath (jar files) and the canonical path refers to package name of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could successfully invoke selenium from XStudio, the following link will guide through the configuration xqual.com/documentation/launchers/selenium_java.html. Please include additional classpath (jar files) and the canonical path refers to package name of the script.